# To verify whether Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

($X,||.||$) is a Banach space and $X=M*N$, where M and N are closed subspaces of X. Let $x \in X$ have a unique representation $x=m+n$, $m \in M$ and $n \in N$
Define $||.||_{1}$ : $X \to R$ by $||x||_{1}$ = $||m||$ + $||n||$, $x \in X$

We need to verify that $(X, ||.||_{1})$ is a Banach space.

This is what I have done so for. Since, $M$ and $N$ are closed subspaces of $X$ and $X$ is Banach so $M$ and $N$ are Banach space $w.r.t$ $||.||$

Now, $||x||_{1} = ||m|| + ||n|| >=0$
and $||x||_{1} = 0$ $iff$ $||m||=0$ and $||n||=0$ $iff$ $m=0$ and $n=0$ $i.e.,$  $x=m+n=0$

Now,$||cx||_{1} = ||cm|| + ||cn|| = |c|||m|| + |c|||n|| = |c|(||m||+||n||)=|c|||x||_{1}$

And,
$||x+y||_{1}$ = $||m_{1} + n_{1} + m_{2} +n_{2}||$

But from here I could not proceed any further. I know I need to show $(X,||.||_{1})$ is a normed linear space and show that X is complete. Can you please help me with how to proceed further?

Comment: $||x+y||_{1}$ = $||m_{1} + n_{1} + m_{2} +n_{2}||\le ||m_{1} \|+ \|n_{1} \|+\|m_{2}\| +\|n_{2}||=\|x\|_1+\|y\|_1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm am I not supposed to verify whether the normed linear space is complete w.r.t to the $||.||_{1}$?

Comment: Yes, start with  a Cauchy sequence, apply the definition of the norm and see how far you can get.

Comment: @geetha290krm Is the fact M and N are Banach spaces aren't enough to claim X to be banach? If not can you please give a bit details about this in form an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x_k\equiv m_k+n_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence then $\|x_k-x_j\|_1=\|m_k+n_k-(m_j+n_j)\|_1=\|m_k-m_j\|+\|n_k-n_j\|\to 0$. This implies that $(m_k)$ and $(n_k)$ are Cauchy sequences, so they converge to some points $m \in M$ and $n \in N$ (because $M$ and $N$ are closed). Can you finish?

Comment: I got it. Thank you.